# BI: Fact Table Design/Data warehouse modelling

Tags: performance, architecture, etl, data-warehouse

i have some issue in designing my Data Warehouse and ETL process because of the fact table. It contains over 100 millions rows for 2 years of accounting data. The dimensions are related to the fact table via Foreign Key, I also used surrogate key , indexes and views. How do you guys would deal with such a fact table in order to ensure a good performance , a reasonable ETL Process and to have an adaptive and resilient to changes Data Warehouse ? It will be partitioning the table by half year a good approach?

Comment: what etl tool you're using? I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am using ssis... I have the data in csv files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should look again at your data-warehouse design.

In fact table, foreign keys combination must be unique per row. If not, there is something wrong with ETL process.

You can easily check this by comparing counts of all rows in fact table with count rows of query where you group by every foreign key (select count(*) from fact_table group by fk1, fk2, fk..n). It has to be equal.

Next, you told that you have surrogate keys as foreign keys. I think that's no reason to repeat you should use integers.

Partition fact table by month, I don't see why on half year period?

100 millions rows is not too big. Perhaps you should think about some columnar database (Vertica for example).

Comment: That's right... I have unicity per row and all my keys are integers and they have nothing to do with the business. They are not showed to the end users. For example, the Account dimension contains AccountNo wich is nvarchar and it's also unique, but instead of using this nvarchar as PK I created a natural integer PK with autoincrement. How would you partitioned the table? The design looks simple... A fact table, one measure: Amount and a couple of parent child dimensions + some bridge tables because of the many-to-many relatioship.

Comment: Please edit your question with data diagram. Maybe there should be need for design changes. If you can eliminate bridge tables in few SQL's, do it! Less joins, faster queries. After that I will suggest you data mart design and index strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I created a columnstore index on the Fact Table and the query cost (relative to the batch) is now 14% with index and 86% without index. I think it's pretty good.
 Execution Plan below.

http://uploadimage.ro/img.php?image=4508_execution_plan_sk6y.png